# How to get the screen height after orientation change?

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I'm getting some strange results when querying `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` after an orientation change. Maybe this isn't the correct way to do it.

I have an observer that listens for the `NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` event:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.orientationChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

This calls a function that sets a constraint to 75% of the new screen height. This works fine on iPhone but iPad returns the wrong screen height.

If the iPad is in **landscape** orientation `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` will return a value equal to the height in **portrait** orientation and vice versa.

```
func orientationChange() {
    // This will print the correct value on iPhone and iPad.
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    self.searchViewHeightConstraint.constant = screenHeight * 0.75

    // Correct value on iPhone. Incorrect on iPad.
    print("screenHeight: '\(screenHeight)'") 

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.searchView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

I've also come across the `viewWilltransition` method of monitoring orientation change but this behaves in the exact opposite way to the method above. ie. the height is correct on iPad but incorrect on iPhone:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    self.searchViewHeightConstraint.constant = screenHeight * 0.75

    // Correct value on iPad. Incorrect on iPhone.
    print("screenHeight: '\(screenHeight)'") 
}
```

What is the reason for this inconsistent behaviour between iPhone and iPad and is using `NotificationCenter` the correct approach to monitoring orientation change?

Comment: Are you getting `screenHeight` value bigger or lesser?

Comment: Stop using the screensize = UIScreen.main.bounds and use size instead, it's given to you in the method. you can do size.height * 0.75

Comment: Also, if you are using constraints and you have your searchView equal to the height of your view, then on that same heighViewConstraint you can set the modifier to 0.75 if it is always going to be that size. Then what you will get is on rotation the view will update itself and you wont have to do any logic at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should be using is 
`viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`. This will give you the size and is WAY more reliable than using a notification.

Also, if you wanted to do animations, inside of the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator you can leverage the method `animate(alongsideTransition animation: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Swift.Void)?, completion: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) -> Bool`

Comment: I have already tried this and it behaves in the exact opposite of the code in my question. ie. it reports the correct dimension on iPad but the wrong dimensions on iPhone.

Comment: Have you tried using the animate(alongsideTransition...)? I have used this and in the completion of that method everything seemed to fall into place.

Comment: So when I created a test project and printed out the size for iPhone I get: `landscape (736.0, 414.0)` and `portrait (414.0, 736.0)` and then for iPad I am getting `landscape (1024.0, 768.0)` and `portrait (768.0, 1024.0)`. These were iPad Air 2 and iPhone 8.

Comment: You are correct about `viewWillTransition`. I should have been using the `size` parameter rather that querying the UIScreen bounds. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
println("h:\(view.bounds.size.height)")
println("w:\(view.frame.size.width)")
         }
```

// All you need to write code under dispatch_async

This code will be executed after the rotation was completed (in the main queue) and the new sizes are available.

Comment: Amen, thank you!

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("Hello")
}

in swift 3/4

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Swift 2.3 for both iPad and iPhone.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    print(size.height)

  if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape {
     print("Landscape")
     print(size.height)

  } 
 else {
      print("Portrait")
      print(size.height)
     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use delay and you will receive recalculated height

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7, execute: {
        // your code hear
})
```